# creating buttons in php but it doesnt detects the function

Tags: php, html, arrays

i have a json array which looks like this

```
array(3) { [0]=> array(8) { ["userid"]=> int(1) ["ticketid"]=> int(1) ["betreff"]=> string(13) "VS Code fehlt" ["raum"]=> string(3) "241" ["nachricht"]=> string(33) "Hey mrq, dings funktioniert nicht" ["bilder"]=> string(12) "guckbild.png" ["zustaendige"]=> int(0) ["status"]=> string(5) "Offen" } [1]=> array(8) { ["userid"]=> int(1) ["ticketid"]=> int(2) ["betreff"]=> string(3) "sad" ["raum"]=> string(2) "23" ["nachricht"]=> string(5) "asasd" ["bilder"]=> string(6) "as.png" ["zustaendige"]=> int(0) ["status"]=> string(5) "Offen" } [2]=> array(8) { ["userid"]=> int(1) ["ticketid"]=> int(3) ["betreff"]=> string(6) "MALWIN" ["raum"]=> string(2) "23" ["nachricht"]=> string(7) "BITTGEH" ["bilder"]=> string(6) "as.png" ["zustaendige"]=> int(0) ["status"]=> string(5) "Offen" } }
```

i am trying to create a list of buttons which has the value of the "betreff" (translated = subject)

This is the loop which i am using right now to create this

```
      for($i = 0; $i<count($json_array); $i++){

    echo '<br><button onClick="setTicketValue(' .$json_array[$i]['ticketid'].')">'.$json_array[$i]['betreff'].'</button>';
  }
```

as you can see ive created a function setTicketValue
In this function it should only change the value of the $_SESSION['ticketid']
Thats the code:

```
      function setTicketValue($ticketid){
    $_SESSION['ticketid'] = $ticketid;
  }
```

When i call the function outside the loop it works, but the buttons with this function doesnt.

Comment: Interaction with html is done with javascript, you can't call PHP functions that way.

Comment: Instead of doing `for($i = 0; $i<count($json_array); $i++)` you could do `foreach ($json_array as $json)`, see: [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). Looks a bit cleaner, without that `$i` stuff and it makes the rest of your code easier to read as well.

Comment: so whats the solution? how can i do this?

Comment: You can use AJAX to call a PHP page that will change the session variable for you. But you always have to ask yourself: "Do I really need to do this?".

Comment: actually, i need to show the tickets which i  am getting from json_array

Comment: i also need a place where i can see the chats from chat_array and also need to send some